# Assembly NASM how to create and work with a search tree without pointers

Tags: search, assembly, recursion, tree, nasm

I have a problem where a guy has to go through several pillars, where they are connected by bridges with holes. The guy must choose the best way trough the pillars. The best way is the way with less holes from the beginning pillar to the last one.

Here is an image provided with the problem.

[image: The Problem]

The program will receive as input a description of the number off holes beetween every pillar and the number of pillars and bridges. The guy must go in only one direction towards the last pillar (no going back).

To me it looks like a tree search problem, but I was told i shouldnt use pointers in this problem cause there is a way to organize and solve it without using classic C tree definitions in assembly (where it d be much harder), only by using recursion.

How can i organize the "way tree" without using dinamic vectors/pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a 'nxn'-matrix (an array of length n^2), where `matrix[i, j]` is the quantity of holes between them. 
If there's  no path between the nodes `i` and `j`, the quantity of holes is infinity (2^31-1). 
Then you can find the best path using recursion or just using the Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i solved the problem using recursion and a matrix, it wasnt returning the best solution everytime, probably cause i didnt implement it right.